# How to not reset form when I switch between tabs

Tags: angular, tabs, bootstrap-4, components

I have two bootstrap tabs and two forms inside. 
I would like to not reset forms when I switch between them.
These forms are in separate components so it's natural that they are destroyed. How can I change this behavior?

parent component

```
 <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"
               routerLinkActive="active"
               [routerLink]="['test1']">Test1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"
               routerLinkActive="active"
               [routerLink]="['test2']">Test2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

test1 child component

```
<form>
 ....
</form>
```

test 2 child component

```
<form>
  ...
</form>
```

So, I would like to have ability to fill form in test1 component, then switch to test2, come back to test1 and still have filled form here.

Comment: Use service to share data on components, as ashissh.gd mentioned below. You can also store info into localstorage or sessionstorage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you rightly said, they are separate components and will be destroyed when switching between tabs which is effective and makes sense.

> The right approach would be to maintain state outside the component
>   i.e. to store the state to a service.

Then, you can always use the service to restore your form in `test1` when navigating back. I would also suggest reading up a bit on Container Vs Presentation components.

Good links:

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

https://blog.angularindepth.com/container-components-with-angular-11e4200f8df